# How to access Portable Class Library Project sqlite method from android project in xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

How to access Portable Class Library Project  ISqliteService or IDialogService or IRestService methods from  android project in xamarin.forms

Comment: First question is why? All of your code to manipulate data should be in your PCL

Comment: it works the same as it would for any external library - just instantiate the class containing the method, and then call it

Comment: @Joagwa I want to save my location details every 10min in sqlite when internet not available or bad network.I write BackroundService for location updation in android project

Comment: And then you BackroundService should call a static (or from singleton) PCL function  which will do the rest